# Convert day of year & year to date Big Query

Tags: sql, date, google-bigquery

I have some data which instead of having a date field, contains the day of the year as a number and the year as a number in different columns.

I have tried using big query functionality `PARSE_DATE` to achieve this by using `PARSE_DATE("%Y %j", "2020 258")` but this does not work.
When checking the docs https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/date_functions#parse_date `%j` is not supported with `PARSE_DATE`.

Does anyone know how I can get around this?

For reference, the following query is as close as I can get:

`SELECT PARSE_DATE("%Y %j", "2020 258")` which returns `2020-01-01`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a brute force method, by adding the number of days to the beginning of he year:

```
select date_add(parse_date('%Y', split(yyyyddd, ' ')[ordinal(1)]),
                interval cast(split(yyyyddd, ' ')[ordinal(2)] as int64) - 1 day
               )
from (select '2020 258' as yyyyddd) x;
```

`PARSE_DATE()` does not support all format elements.  As the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/date_functions) (rather defensively) explains:

> The format string fully supports most format elements except for %Q, %a, %A, %g, %G, %j, %u, %U, %V, %w, and %W.

Comment: This works perfectly thank you! I saw the documentation doesn't support the %j method.